# Jboss fuse imported packages

Tags: maven, jboss, osgi, apache-felix, jbossfuse

When I try to deploy my route in Jboss fuse this probelm show up:
[image]

I had configured the felix plugin to imports this packages but without a result

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
        <Import-Package>org.jasypt.encryption.pbe, 
                         com.google.gson, 
                        javax.ws.rs, 
                        javax.xml.bind.annotation, 
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json, 
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml, 
                        org.apache.camel, 
                         org.apache.camel.builder,
                         org.apache.camel.model,* 
        </Import-Package>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Can I have a explanation for this problem? and a permanent solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You also need install bundles which can export those packages.

Comment: How I can do that ?